# electron use 'nodejs-pptx' not working production environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

It works fine in development environment, but not in production environment.
electron use nodejs-pptx not working production environment.
but development working in environment..

```js
//production
console.log('1')
const PPTX = require('nodejs-pptx'); 
console.log('2')
const pptx = new PPTX.Composer(); // ignore line.. 
console.log('3')


//out put
1
2
```

i want reason not working..

Comment: Is it in the `dependencies` list in your `package.json`? Make sure it isn't saved in `devDependencies` instead.

Comment: @skara9 thank you. but 'nodejs-pptx' in dependencies..